# foreach loop for two variables in laravel

Tags: php, variables, foreach, laravel-7

below is my codes in controller and php file. How do I run the foreach for both $posts and $users? I have tried @foreach(array_merge($posts,$users) as $post) but doesn't work.

WelcomeController:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    $users = User::all();
    return view('welcome', [
        'posts' => $posts,
        'users' => $users
    ]);
}
```

blade.php:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="content">
                        <img src="/storage/{{$post->image}}" style="width:100%" id="myImg">
                        <h4>By {{$user->name}}</h4>
                        <p>{{$post->caption}}</p>
                        <p class="description">{{$post->description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use one to many (inverse) relationship [visit](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

In post model add:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

And in blade.php:

```
{{ $post->user->name }}
```